# Read an html or php page with windows phone and get data

Tags: c#, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to read a html or php page. I need to get all artists names of this page: http://www.unnu.com/music-artists please help me out with this. I'm trying at the moment using the HtmlAgilityPack but I can not get any data. Can anyone help me?

```
private void Artistas()
        {
             // acesso o site e recupero seu conteudo
            WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create("http://www.dmenezes.com.br").GetResponse();

            // aqui começa o uso da Html Agility Pack
            // crio um HtmlDocument com o conteudo do site já recuperado
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());


            // selecionando todos os links do menu principal, e mostrando seus endereços.

            var linksMenuPrincipal = doc.GetElementbyId("menu-principal").DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Name == "a");

            foreach (HtmlNode link in linksMenuPrincipal)

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("O endereço de [{0}] é {1}", link.Attributes["title"].Value, link.Attributes["href"].Value));
        }
```

this is how I'm trying, but I do not know if this correct!

Comment: What indication do you have that it's not correct?

Comment: this is a code example, I want to get the site I cited data from the artists and need to know how to do. Not to mention that the "GetResponse ()" does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work."  We can't debug this for you.  In what way does this code not behave as expected?  Do you get an error message?  An unexpected result?  What is the runtime behavior and how is it not working?

Comment: I'd love to pass the code for you to do this filter to me. Could put the project at some site and you download. I do not even know if I am on the right path because it is the first time you try to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that looks correct, use this xpath /html/body/div/li/ul/li